# Twitter OAuth: There is no request token for this page

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm using Abraham's `TwitterOAuth` library to implement Twitter OAuth in my application. However, on clicking the `Login` button, users are sometimes redirected to the following page:

[image]

I said 'sometimes', because sometimes the Twitter OAuth provider does generate the request token, and the users are taken to the 'Grant Permission' page.

Is this a library issue? Or is this an issue with the Twitter OAuth provider? If there was an issue with my code, then this page should appear every time a user tries to login using his/her Twitter account, and not at random tries.

Here's the code of the template that the users are redirected to after clicking the `Login` button:

```
<?php

/*
 *Template Name: OAuth

*/

?>

<pre>

<?php

    session_start();
    require "twitteroauth/autoload.php";
    use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

    define('CONSUMER_KEY', "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    define('CONSUMER_SECRET', "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    define('OAUTH_CALLBACK', "http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/callback/");

    $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
    $request_token = $connection->oauth('oauth/request_token', array('oauth_callback' => OAUTH_CALLBACK));
    $_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $request_token['oauth_token'];
    $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];

    $url = $connection->url('oauth/authorize', array('oauth_token' => $request_token['oauth_token']));

    header('Location: '.$url);
?>

</pre>
```

PS: I also tried regenerating the `Consumer Key` and `Consumer Secret`, but that doesn't seem to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two scenarios that seem most likely to me are:

1) There is an error while getting the request token. Try adding some error handling.

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
$request_token = $connection->oauth('oauth/request_token', array('oauth_callback' => OAUTH_CALLBACK));
if ($connection->getLastHttpCode() == 200) {
    $_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $request_token['oauth_token'];
    $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];
    $url = $connection->url('oauth/authorize', array('oauth_token' => $request_token['oauth_token']));
    header('Location: '.$url);
} else {
    var_dump($request_token);
    exit('Error getting request_token');
}
```

2) Twitter has a bug where it's not recognizing the the request_token for some reason.

The next step in debugging is to find out the status of $request_token that results in the error.

Comment: There was indeed an error while getting the request token. Error handling solved my issue. Thanks a ton, Abraham! One quick question: why did just preparing to handle an error prevented the error from triggering altogether? Everything else is exactly the same as it was in my original code, but why did error handling completely prevented the error from occurring?

Comment: I tried working on my application again later this morning, and I'm still encountering the same issue while generating the request token, although now it gets captured by the error handling mechanism in the code. The core problem, however, still persists.